# Get the initial value after several map/filter calls

Tags: ruby

I have an enumerable that goes through several transformation steps and a final filter step

E.g

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].map{|i| i * 2}
                   .map{|i| i * i}
                   .filter{|i| i % 3 ==0 }
                   .each{|i| puts how_do_i_get_initial_value_here }
                   .or_the_initial_value_here
```

How do I get the initial value whose transformations satisfied the filter?

Thus in the above example, how do I end up with `[3,6,9]` instead of `[36, 144, 324]`

Comment: Please edit to clarify your question. Are you asking the following: given the array `arr` that is the receiver of `each`, what values of the initial array map into the receiver of `each`? What do you mean by "final filter", as opposed to "filter"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to carry original value to the final step.

Object-oriented approach can help by introducing a "filter" type

```
class Filter
  attr_reader :value

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value 
  end

  def satisfies?
    (value * 2 * value) % 3 == 0
  end
end
```

Usage

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].map { |i| Filter.new(i) }.select(&:satisfies?).map(&:value)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply apply the transformations that you do in the two `map` calls directly in `filter`:

```rb
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  .filter { |i| (i * 2)**2 % 3 == 0 }
```

Alternatively, you could keep the original value in a "tuple" as follows:

```rb
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  .map { |i| [i, i] }
  .map { |a, b| [a, b * 2] }
  .map { |a, b| [a, b * b] }
  .filter { |a, b| b % 3 == 0 }
  .map { |a, _| a }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are given a method:

```
def f(n)
  4 * n**2
end
```

where `f(n)` is the transformed value of an element `n` from the given array (as `(2 * n)*(2 * n) = 4 * n**2)`).

`f` is a 1-1 mapping, so it has an inverse method `g` (i.e., `g(f(n)) #=> n` for all integers `n`):

```
def g(m)
  Math.sqrt(m).round/2
end
```

(We need `.round` because of round-off errors.)

Suppose we have:

```
arr
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

then

```
z = arr.map { |n| f(n) }.filter { |x| x % 3 == 0 }
  #=> [36, 144, 324]
```

Then the inverse of these values is given by:

```
z.map { |m| g(m) }
  #=> [3, 6, 9]
```

Notice that:

```
arr.map { |n| f(n) }.filter { |x| x % 3 == 0 }
```

is the same as:

```
arr.filter { |x| x % 3 == 0 }.map { |n| f(n) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just undo the things you did. So

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  .map{ |i| i * 2 }
  .map{ |i| i * i }
  .filter{ |i| i % 3 ==0 }
  .map{ |i| Math.sqrt(i) / 2 }
```

Comment: Testing answers before posting is always advised.

Comment: Well `filter` isn't a Ruby method, so you can't test this code. I tested my answer with `select`. But the backslash was obviously just a typo in transferring the answer over.

Comment: [Array#filter](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-filter) was added as an alias of `Array#select` in v2.6. (I forgot it was that recent.)

Comment: Good to know. We're still on v2.4 where I work. And I do so little Ruby outside of work, I haven't really been keeping up :/

Comment: You don't mean :\ ? :-)